# How to enqueue scripts in my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to use JavaScript (JQuery) within my plugin. The enqueueing should not be inside the themes' function.php. Imagine telling your users "Please to add this line of code in your functions.php etc..."

/plugins/foo-plugin/foo-plugin.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Foo Plugin
 * Plugin URI: foobar.com
 * Description: ___DEV___
 * Version: 1.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

function Foo_Plugin() {
    return Foo_Plugin::instance();
} // End Foo_Plugin()

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'Foo_Plugin' );

/**
 * Load Scrips
 */
function enqueue_js() {
    // JS
  wp_enqueue_script( 'foo', './assets/js/foo.js', false );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_js');

[...]
```

I've followed [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) but I'm not getting my output:

```
//foo.js:
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("foo is ready")
})
```

I have deactivated/reactivated the plugin and nothing. How to use JS/CSS in my plugin? As you've guested, it's my first time creating one ;)

Path to JS:

```
/plugins/foo-plugin/assets/js/foo.js
```

Comment: If you view the source do you see it? Maybe your path is wrong but the <script> tag is still being added (which means your code does work).

Comment: @OfirBaruch It's not in there. Ive now used `wp_enqueue_scripts(...)`

Comment: Is this script for the front end or admin?

Comment: @Erin The plugin is for a backend (admin). Not frontend.

Comment: Ohh, there's a different hook for the backend assets loading. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the admin section, use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action hook.

```
function enqueue_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'foo', './assets/js/foo.js');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_js');
```

Also, don't put that `false` in there. The default should be an empty array if there are no dependencies.

Comment: Ok doing that I got `Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks.`

Comment: Sweet! Thanks very much